# i need span values in this html using jquery

Tags: jquery

In this html i need a values of span that contain class="values"

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="StatusList" style="width: 300px; display: none">
    <option value="Open">Open</option>
    <option value="InProgress">InProgress</option>
    <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
    <option value="Onhold">Onhold</option>
    <option value="FollowUp">FollowUp</option>
    <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
</select>
<div class="ms-parent" id="List">
    <button type="button" id="text" class="ms-choice" style="width: 294px">
        <span class="values">InProgress,  Closed,  Onhold</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

helps are mostly appreciable. thank you

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: This is the basic answer you can find on any jQuery website

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=wQ_gUt-XIoLWrQeDjYHIDg#q=i+need+span+values+in+this+html+using+jquery

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ and http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/. What you need is mentioned at the beginning of those two pages. It almost seems like you haven't even bothered reading the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var text = $('#text .values').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this selector `$('span.values').text()`

So to get it in a variable just use:

```
var myText = $('span.values').text();
```